# How to format/restore USB where its partition's contents 'unknown'

Tags: partitioning, usb, disk, disk-usage

I have an old USB of mine I messed up not too long ago and haven't been able to fix. It currently is partioned into two halves: one ~64 GB and the other ~>1 MB.

I'd like to be able to use it today, but when I *right-click → format → ...* using the Files app it doesn't seem to do anything.

Using Disks I have the following screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Would anyone be able to walk me through restoring my USB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Format Disk` in "Gnome-Disks":

[image]

If that does not work try **mkusb** `restore to a Standard storae device`.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive

[image]

Sometimes USB devices just die.

Comment: The first suggestion seemed to have worked, as it now reads 'Free Space 64 GB'. Except it is not showing up in my the *Files* navigation launcher. It is detected in *Gnome Disks* (or just *Disks*), but not where I can use it.